# 2 kind of command in Command Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, command-pattern

I'm developing application using Command Pattern. I have two kind of operations in my programm: 
 1. Long time operations (copy/delete files), which should be run asynchronously
 2. Simple operations (refresh panels)

My question is: Can I implement 2 kind of commands in this Pattern (AsyncCmd and SimpleCmd)? And before Executing in Command Manager check type of command:

```
public void Execute()
   {
     if(cmd is AsyncCmd)
        {
         RunAsyncOperation();
        }
     else if(cmd is SimpleCmd)
        {
         RunOperation();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could , but using if else for defining the type of operation defeats the purpose of the command patter . The asynchronous and simple (I guess synchronous) should be separate commands each inheriting from ICommand (which has one method Execute()) . These commands should be created using factories which can deal with command specific contexts  , e.g. Anything special you have to do for asynchronous operations etc.